# How can I put ng-model from $scope array and send it to another scope function? (angularjs)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, onsen-ui

i want to take data for an array called cl from the product array. this line `<input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Ποσότητα" value="" ng-model="item.rowid">` is my problem. the ng-model doesn't work with type number. I get the Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected '**product1**' to be a number, and when i make it **type="text"** it puts product1 for value and i want it only for bind name. then i decide to put also in the cl array as you gonna see farther down. (sry for my english, it isn't my native)

this is my code:

```
<ons-page>
<ons-navigator>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Κωδ. Πελάτη" value="" ng-model="cl.Code">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Ημερ. παράδοσης" value="" ng-model="cl.Livraison">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Σημειώσεις (δημόσιες)" value="" ng-model="cl.NotesPub">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Σημειώσεις (προσωπικές)" value="" ng-model="cl.NotesPer">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Συνθήκες Πληρωμής
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <select ng-model="cl.Cond">
                    <option value="1">Άμεση</option>
                    <option value="2">30 Μέρες</option>
                    <option value="3">30 Μέρες (τέλος μήνα)</option>
                    <option value="4">60 Μέρες</option>
                    <option value="5">60 Μέρες (τέλος μήνα)</option>
                    <option value="6">Κατόπιν Παραγγελίας</option>
                    <option value="7">Αποστολή</option>
                    <option value="8">50-50</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Τύπος Πληρωμής
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <select ng-model="cl.mode">
                    <option value="1">TIP</option>
                    <option value="2">Τραπεζική Κατάθεση</option>
                    <option value="3">Εντολή Τράπεζας</option>
                    <option value="4">Μετρητά</option>
                    <option value="6">Πιστωτική Κάρτα</option>
                    <option value="7">Επιταγή</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Καθυστέρηση Διαθεσιμότητα
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <select ng-model="cl.Avail">
                    <option value="1">Άμεση</option>
                    <option value="2">1 Εβδομάδα</option>
                    <option value="3">2 Εβδομάδες</option>
                    <option value="4">3 Εβδομάδες</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in product">
            <td>{{item.label}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Ποσότητα" value="" ng-model="cl.item.rowid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="newOrder(client.rowid,cl)">Προσθήκη</ons-button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ons-navigator>
```

`

and this is my controler:

```
 $scope.newOrder = function (clRowId,cl) {
    console.log(clRowId);
    console.log(cl);
    $http.post($rootScope.IP + 'newOrder.php', { 'clRowId': clRowId, 'userId': $rootScope.rowid }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //alert(data);
        })
};

$scope.getProduct = function () {
    $http.post($rootScope.IP + 'product.php', '').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.product = data;

            console.log(row);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //alert(data);
        })
};
```

JSON posted in comments:

```
[{
"rowid":"product1",
"label":"\u03a0\u03c1\u03bf\u03ca\u03cc\u03bd1",
"price":"81‌​.30081000",
"ref":"\u03a00001",
"fk_product_type":"0",
"tosell":"1",
"tobuy":"1",
"tms‌​":"21-02-2015",
"price_base_type":"TTC",
"datec":"21-02-2015"},
{
"rowid":"product2",
‌​"label":"\u03a5\u03c0\u03b7\u03c1\u03b5\u03c3\u03af\u03b11",
"price":"162.60163000‌​",
"ref":"\u03a50001",
"fk_product_type":"1",
"tosell":"1",
"tobuy":"1",
"tms":"21-02-‌​2015",
"price_base_type":"TTC",
"datec":"21-02-2015"}]
```

Comment: can you post some sample JSON for the `product` which you are trying to display?

Comment: [{"rowid":"product1","label":"\u03a0\u03c1\u03bf\u03ca\u03cc\u03bd1","price":"81.30081000","ref":"\u03a00001","fk_product_type":"0","tosell":"1","tobuy":"1","tms":"21-02-2015","price_base_type":"TTC","datec":"21-02-2015"},{"rowid":"product2","label":"\u03a5\u03c0\u03b7\u03c1\u03b5\u03c3\u03af\u03b11","price":"162.60163000","ref":"\u03a50001","fk_product_type":"1","tosell":"1","tobuy":"1","tms":"21-02-2015","price_base_type":"TTC","datec":"21-02-2015"}]

Comment: So based on the JSON that I moved from the comments into your question, it appears that your data has `"rowid":"product1"` but you only want `1` to be bound in your textbox?

Comment: i want the bind name to be product1. The textbox i want to be number type for the quantity of the product, which I want to send it to mysql. It's an app for order (if this can help to understand what i do)

Comment: I'm still lost.  did you mean for `ng-model` to be set to the `rowid`, the `tobuy` value, or something else?  I've read the question a few times, looked at the code, the JSON you added, and I still can't really figure out what you are trying to do.  I think you are misunderstanding what `ng-model` is used for, but I'm not clear on what you need to accomplish to give you an explanation.

Comment: Actually it is pritty simple. I created a page for a salesman. The page above is the form for the order, so at 
`<tr ng-repeat="item in product">
...
 <td><input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Ποσότητα" value="" ng-model="cl.item.rowid"></td>
        </tr>` 
I bring the products from mysql server via **getProduct** function. Then i want to put a number for each product to make the order. So my question is this: How can i print the products in the page to a deferent input which its type is number and then to get the quantity from **newOrder** function?

Comment: ok, so the number you want to print in that textbox is **not** the `rowid`, it is a new value for how much should be ordered?

Comment: Exactly. The rowid, I want to use it for the input name that I call from the function to get the value number

Comment: your attempts at explanation make it even more clear that you don't know how `ng-model` works.  you need a *different* variable to store the value in, and that is what should be passed to your function.

Comment: i use **ng model** in input like the name in html5's input. if that is the wrong way, which is the correct one?

Comment: `ng-model` binds the `expression` to the `value`, not the `name` on the element.  if you want your expression bound to the name, why not `name={{rowid}}`? though I'm not sure how that makes the value in the textbox able to be passed to the function....